# Change in rotation of a tank-like vehicle

Tags: language-agnostic, formula

I'm trying to simulate a tank-like/skid-steered vehicle, i.e. both of the wheels (one on each side) have separate velocities, and steering is done by increasing or decreasing the velocity of one of the sides.

For example, If I set the velocity of the left wheel to 5, and the right wheel to 3, it will turn right. What I'd like to know is, given the velocities of the wheels Vl and Vr, and the distance between the wheels D, by how many degrees will the direction the vehicle is pointing in change in one tick?

I've tried looking at [Formula for controlling the movement of a tank-like vehicle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125099/formula-for-controlling-the-movement-of-a-tank-like-vehicle), and the links on that question, but haven't come up with anything. All my best guesses have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: the really easy edge cases. if `V_l` and `V_r` are zero, don't move. If they're the same, don't turn.

Second, if only one of `V_l` and `V_r` are zero, the tank pivots around the stationary tread, and the moving tread traces out an arc of length `V_big` with a radius of curvature `D`. `theta = Vbig/D`, plus or minus some sign conventions based on your coordinates. (the tank base also translates some distance but the calculations for that are dependent on where the center of rotation of the tank is defined to be and your coordinate system, so that detail is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Third, symmetry concerns! Obviously tank treads turning is left/right symmetric. If the left tread is twice as fast as the right the tank should turn the same amount as if the right tread is twice as fast as the left, just in a different direction. Ditto for going backwards.

Fourth: Meat and potatoes! I'm assuming neither tank tread can slip whatsoever. The faster tread traces an arc of length `V_fast` on a circle of radius `r+D` marked out by an angle `theta`. If you recall your trig `V_fast=(r+D)*theta`. The slower wheel traces out an arc of length `V_slow` on a circle of radius `r` marked out by the same angle.(`V_slow = theta*r`) Divide one equation by the other, receive `V_fast/V_slow = (r+D)/r`. Apply algebra to provide `r=D/((V_fast/V_slow)-1)` Note that this explodes appropriately when `V_slow` is zero or when `V_fast=V_slow`, and you appropriately receive `r=D` when `V_fast=2*V_slow` Recall that `theta=V_slow*r`: `theta=(V_fast-V_slow)/D`

IN RADIANS, mind you That's a crucial detail.

NOTE: If you define 'turning right' as positive theta and turning left as negative theta, it all works out and `theta=(V_l-V_r)/D`, even for negative speeds. The tank won't turn around to face the direction of travel, it'll keep facing the correct way.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: How does one mathjax? Can one mathjax on SO?